# javascript get string text from json data

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, material-ui

I'm creating a table in react using material UI and trying to figure out how to extract itemlocation from itemInfo and store it in a new column in the table. I know I can do it from the back end, but I can't, and all I want is to be able to extract the string from the item info. I provided an example of how the table and I'll put should look, as well as a snippet of sample code, and I hope this helps because this is how I was thinking of doing it, and I was hoping if anyone knew how I could do it without going into the backend.

simple code

```
 const columns1 = [{
      field: "itemInfo",
      headerName: "itemInfo",
      headeralign: "center",
      align: "left",
      width: "136",
      type: "string",
      editable: true,
    },
{
      field: "itemlocation",
      headerName: " itemlocation",
      headeralign: "center",
      align: "left",
      width: "136",
      type: "string",
      editable: true,
      renderCell: (params) => {
        return (
          <> </>
        );
      }
    },]
```

Json data

```
const Rows =[{
            "id": "2433-10",
            "busiName": "ABC",
            "srTypeId": "2433-10",
            "nodeType": "0",
            "pathName": "home",
            "busiSort": 10,
            "itemInfo": "1:sql test question:  itemlocation=USA",
            "superTypeId": "002",}]
```

Original MUI Table

| itemid | itemname | itemInfo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | car | 1:sql test question: itemlocation=USA |
| 99 | toy | 1:sql test question: itemlocation=USA |

I want extract just itemlocation from itemInfo into New table columns

| itemid | itemname | itemInfo | itemlocation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | car | 1:sql test question: itemlocation=USA | USA |
| 99 | toy | 1:sql test question: itemlocation=USA | CHAIN |

Comment: What code have you tried to attempt to retrieve said string? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for what you've tried already in solving this problem. Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Can can't help diagnose/debug code we can't see.

Answer (score -1):

If you already have access to `itemInfo` you could run a method similiar to below

```
const extractLocation = (itemInfo) => {
    return itemInfo.match(/itemlocation=(.*)/)[1]
}
```

This uses regular expression matching to find just the text after `itemlocation`. If you expect other text that isnt the location to be added to your itemInfo string later on you can update it to exclude that text.

To call this method(assuming your json data is an array of object) you could do.

```
const location = extractLocation(json[0]['iteminfo'])

// or for all locations

const locations = json.map((item) => {
 return extractLocation(item['itemInfo'])
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let newFormat = items.map(item => {
    return {
        newProperty: item.oldProperty
    }
});
```

Comment: Please see [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for details on how to provide quality answers. It's useful to provide context and details on why this might be an ideal solution.

Comment: Please read "[answer]" and "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.